# Programmatically installing SSL certificate in iPhone by placing the certificate in application bundle in Monotouch

Tags: ssl, xamarin.ios, ssl-certificate

I am writing an iPhone application using Monotouch and I have to access WCF web services   which are secured using https. I have installed the certificate in the Mac machine and everything works in the Mac and the simulator. Now in iPhone i want to install the certificate by placing the .cer file in app bundle programmatically. Please let me know how this can be done.I am a new bee in Monotouch so i do not know much about this.

Is there some code that I can use to achieve this? 
If this cannot be done is there any other way i can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You probably already know that WS-* is all built on top of http requests, and any time you are doing loads of http requests, you'll probably find ASIHTTPRequest very helpful on the iPhone. However, that will not get you 100% of the way there.

From the iPhone's perspective you have:

```
1 The URL loading system, which is a high level API for dealing with network resources of any kind
2 The CFNetwork C API which is lower-level and allows you a great deal more control of encrypting streams and network traffic any way you see fit
3 The Certificate, Key, and Trust Services that do the heavy lifting, and more specifically the X509 trust policies
```

On Macs you get to use Secure Transport, but as far as I know they haven't ported that to the device so I wouldn't get too distracted reading up on that unless you are planning on bringing this to the desktop or are just in the mood to learn everything.

If you are doing any security with WCF, the first thing you probably realized is that there are many options available to you, but it all boils down to this short list:

```
1 Transport layer security (https) with clear text messages (xml/json/...)
2 Message layer security (encrypted message body) over an open transport (http)
3 Secured messages over a secured transport
```

Once you get something working, you'll want to refer to the [Enterprise Deployment Guide](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/Enterprise_Deployment_Guide.pdf), and specifically the documentation on Over-the-Air Enrollment so that you can install the certificates on the devices. Remember, anything is possible, and don't be afraid to use one of those Apple support tickets that come with the program :)

Comment: Anoop, Thanks for the answer. But it would help me if u can share me some code on how to access the keychain in iphone and read the file